# Pip install fails

Tags: python

I'm trying to install a package for python with the following error being given.

```
Collecting andor
  Using cached andor-1.14.tar.gz (237 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: andor
  Building wheel for andor (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\BioPhotonics\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xhxcidrk\\andor_d3d6c6374a5f483cb478ca158e6bf226\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BioPhotonics\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xhxcidrk\\andor_d3d6c6374a5f483cb478ca158e6bf226\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\BioPhotonics\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-3_wi37w3'
       cwd: C:\Users\BioPhotonics\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xhxcidrk\andor_d3d6c6374a5f483cb478ca158e6bf226\
  Complete output (13 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  skipping 'andor2.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  building 'andor2' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -I.. -IC:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I/usr/lib64/python/site-packages/Cython/Includes -IC:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcandor2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\andor2.obj
  andor2.c
  C:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
  andor2.c(244): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atmcdLXd.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for andor
  Running setup.py clean for andor
Failed to build andor
Installing collected packages: andor
    Running setup.py install for andor ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\BioPhotonics\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xhxcidrk\\andor_d3d6c6374a5f483cb478ca158e6bf226\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BioPhotonics\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xhxcidrk\\andor_d3d6c6374a5f483cb478ca158e6bf226\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BioPhotonics\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fkljfz5y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\Include\andor'
         cwd: C:\Users\BioPhotonics\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xhxcidrk\andor_d3d6c6374a5f483cb478ca158e6bf226\
    Complete output (13 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    skipping 'andor2.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'andor2' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -I.. -IC:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I/usr/lib64/python/site-packages/Cython/Includes -IC:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcandor2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\andor2.obj
    andor2.c
    C:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    andor2.c(244): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atmcdLXd.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\BioPhotonics\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xhxcidrk\\andor_d3d6c6374a5f483cb478ca158e6bf226\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BioPhotonics\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xhxcidrk\\andor_d3d6c6374a5f483cb478ca158e6bf226\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BioPhotonics\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fkljfz5y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\BioPhotonics\anaconda3\Include\andor' Check the logs for full command output.

(base) C:\Users\BioPhotonics>
```

Comment: It seems that you need a deprecated version of NumPy but you have a more modern version. Thus, a file you are requesting is missing. Can you provide your NumPy version?

Comment: Thanks, I have 1.20.1

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: I'm on Python 3.8

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about andor's compatibility with Python 3... from its PyPi site, I can only see examples with Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue of the andor package. I've been reading through [its files](https://pypi.org/project/andor/#files) and the `setup.py` file does not specify a NumPy version. As the latest release of the package is from 2016, I suppose that NumPy's current version is no longer compatible with andor. I suggest you to install an older version of NumPy (perhaps the 1.7) and then try to install andor again.

EDIT: I found the following information in its `setup.py` file:

- The package is for Python 2.7
- Its author is Guillaume Lepert (guillaume.lepert07@imperial.ac.uk). Maybe you can contact him so he can give you more information about this package.

Comment: Thanks anyway! FYI I switched to a Python 2.7 but it still won't install.

Comment: Yes I also tried in Python 2.7. The issue is that the latest version of NumPy for Python 2.7 is still not compatible with andor.